# How can I add/change the parent of an entity after it has been created but before it is put in the Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

From what I've read in the docs, it's impossible to change the parent of an entity after it has been put in the datastore. But I am looking for a way to change the parent before that happens (but after it is created). So instead of having this:

```py
John = Student(parent=BlueClassroom.key, name="John", last_name="Smith")
John.put()
```

I am looking for something like this:

```py
John = Student(name="John", last_name="Smith")
John.parent = BlueClassroom.key
John.put()
```

Now, the first one works, but the second one does not (it just ignores the second line). I have also tried to use populate, but that just works for regular properties. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: The statement `John.parent = BlueClassroom.key` is not changing the key, it is only adding a new property called `parent` to the entity `John`.

Your first example is the correct way to set the parent of the key, why not use that when you know the parent?

Comment: Because I don't know what the parent is at that stage, that is determined in another function. I should probably rearrange everything so that I can do it in a single place, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do it the way it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [NDB Model Class Constructor](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Constructor) docs:

> You cannot easily define a property named "key", "id", "parent", or
>   "namespace". If you pass, for example, key="foo" in a constructor or
>   populate() call, it sets the entity's key, not a property attribute
>   named "key".

I'd suggest passing the data around as a dict until you're ready to create the entity:

```
john = {name="John", last_name="Smith"}
...
John = Student(parent=BlueClassroom.key)
John.populate(john)
```

Comment: I had seen that in the docs, but I wanted to know if there was still a way to define a parent after that (but before putting it). Since I can't find a way to do it, I will just pass the data as a dict.